# Does String.init(cString: UnsafePointer<Int8>) copy the memory contents?

Tags: swift, string, pointers, memory

What are the inner workings?

Does it create a Swift string copy of the C string data?

Does it use it as a reference and return it as a Swift string, so the string returned uses the same data? How does it work?

Does it copy the C string into a newly allocated Swift string?

If `String(cString: UnsafePointer<Int8>)` indeed works by copying the C string into a newly allocated swift string, is there a way to convert C strings to swift by referencing the already existing data instead of copying it?

How does `String(cString: UnsafePointer<Int8>)` work, and how can I determine whether it copies, or whether it references the same memory as a Swift string?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641523-init "Creates a new string by copying the null-terminated UTF-8 data referenced by the given pointer."

Comment: I tried editing your question to make it a bit less of a wall-of-text, but there's still lots of duplication, askign the same question in different ways. Could you please edit it down as you see appropriate?

Comment: Also, the implementation is open source. You can dive into it yourself if you're so interested: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b8c74b491ee83379645c750c356ebb133c279e15/stdlib/public/core/CString.swift#L19-L50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641523-init) clearly states that the data is copied:

> #### Initializer
>
> ### init(cString:)
>
> Creates a new string by copying the null-terminated UTF-8 data referenced by the given pointer.

---

> is there a way to convert C strings to swift by referencing the already existing data instead of copying it?

Nope. Strings are frequently copied/destroyed, which involves doing retain/release operations on the underlying buffer, to do the necessary booking keeping of thethe reference count. If the memory is not owned by the String, then there's no way to reliably de-allocate it.

What are you trying to achieve by avoiding the copy?